# Do processor commands and values have binary codes?

Tags: logic-gates

I am working on a diy computer and I am struggling to understand how processors handle information. I would like my diy computer to be able to do the bare minimum, for example calculator, output text. But since I will only be using commands in binary, do I have to come up with my own syntax for command handling. Such as: Data (some binary digits), adress (adress in binary), how to handle the information (binary code for a command)

I'm no expert in computer science, but as far as I understand, each 2 bits have a hexadecimal value and all bits have a decimal value. So if I program my diy cpu to think that say 1001 = add how will I be able to differentiate between that command and the decimal value?

Comment: Make order and position matter.

Comment: You should study the instruction sets and coding for a couple of early 8-bit processors, such as the Motorola 6800 or Intel 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think best way to start think about it is [logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) that can be arranged to adders, flip-flops and basically everything you need. Then you just apply your binary command to command pins, binary data to data pins and take output value from output pins. So you can have 1001 on command pins and 1001 on data pins meaning different things, because they are applied in different locations. Also you can access commands and data on same pins, but at different time.
If you know how to make logic ciruits you get the idea, when you make some specific logic circuit you clearly have pins that are responsible for command, separate pins for data input and maybe some other pins.
Inside microcontroller this is probably much more sophisticated, since you can't make entirely new logic circuit every time. I am not sure how this is done precisely, but I would guess they have bunch of pre-made logic blocks that are routed(with transistors probably) depending on the code.
If you start to think about memory and addresses then it starts to be more confusing, but essentially it can be broken down to logic gates level and maybe some analog stuff, if needed(like in ADCs or some tricky constructions).

There is also FPGA, where you can basically re-build logic circuit every time you program it, though inside they really use LookUp Tables(LUTs), basically mapping logical functions to truth tables, but it is the same thing in the end.

Different technologies do stuff different inside, e.g. FPGA is not at all like microcontroller. But if you will break them block by block they are all built of transistors doing stuff. The problem is - you would spend so much time breaking down the operation principle of them so you basically need to be VLSI designer to know everything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal and hexadecimal have nothing to do with it. These are just different ways of expressing the same pattern. Binary `1001` is hexadecimal 0x9, unsigned decimal 9, and signed 4-bit decimal "negative 7". Those are just ways for a person to write the number, the computer only sees the binary pattern.

Assuming that your "diy computer" uses a `Von Neumann Architecture` (as most machines do), with instructions and data stored in the same memory, the only way to distinguish between instructions and data is by context. During the instruction fetch phase, whatever is read from memory at the instruction pointer, is assumed to be an instruction. Immediate data is fetched during a subsequent phase, if applicable. Some instructions may only require the instruction code itself, while other instructions may require additional data bytes stored in subsequent locations. So not every memory location necessarily contains an instruction.

An alternative is to use `Harvard Architecture`, with separate memories for instruction and data. This is used on TMS320 digital signal processor chips.

One of the biggest problems you're going to have with this project is that you have to do all your work in your own custom machine language, unless you also write your own assembler and compiler. Since you say you don't currently know much computer science, it might be easier to start "retrocomputing" using an older microcontroller architecture that already has assemblers, compilers, and libraries that you can use.

You might want to look into the architecture of some older microcontrollers, such as the `6502` or `Motorola 68HC11`, the `Intel 8080`, and maybe even `8051` (although that one has some quirks). Might also be worth looking on opencores.org for some HDL implementations, even if you aren't using an FPGA. There's a lot that has been written about these microcontrollers, so this should give some helpful context to understand the basic problems.

Comment: Motorola made the 6800 and 6809.  Someone else (I forget who) made the 6502.

Comment: @PeterBennett good catch, I'd forgotten that -- think maybe it was Mostek or Rockwell; current search turns up Western Design Center as a current manufacturer.